# How does Cersei pay her bills?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones S07E04, the conversation between Cersei and the Iron Bank representative reveals that she plans to repay the crown's debt to the Iron Bank with gold recovered in the conquest of Highgarden.  The Iron Bank representative is impressed and conditionally agrees to extend further credit for Cersei's wars upon the repayment of the prior loans.

However, Jaime's army marching the gold home to King's Landing is attacked by Daenarys (with her dragons) and the Dothraki.  I think it is made abundantly clear that Jaime loses this battle at the end of S07E04, and Daenarys's forces win control of the field.  Jaime's wagons are burned and his armies are decimated.  At the beginning of S07E05, the Dothraki are seen leisurely picking over the battlefield for good steel while Jaime is off getting half-drowned and waking up alone on the river bank with Ser Bron of the Blackwater, his highborn commanders off being executed by dragonfire.

Yet, in the very next scene we see Jaime explaining his defeat to Cersei, and she still seems confident that the Iron Bank is going supply her with gold for making war.  Why?  Is Daenarys allergic to gold?  Have I missed something?

Comment: Insert low-hanging fruit joke about always paying debts here.

Comment: Also related - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78613/why-does-cersei-need-to-repay-the-iron-bank-right-now

Comment: You know, I searched Cersei Iron Bank before asking, and reviewed the suggested questions while asking, and that topic never came up.  Weird.